# How to control null LookUp or Compare different types of List

Tags: linq, compare

I have something like this which is getting string categories (from dropdown).

I am taking all list in `catList` and comparing that item in `string[]categories` and if it  is `null` add this to `newCategories` for add to database. And lastly i want to return `List<Category>` with `categories` values.

```
public List<Category> ExistingCategories(string[] categories)
{
    var catList = GetAllCategories().ToList();
    List<Category> newCategories = new List<Category>();

    var existedCategory = catList.ToLookup(x=>x.Name , v=>v.Name);

    foreach (var item in categories)
    {
        var lookUpExistedCategory = existedCategory[item];

        if (lookUpExistedCategory != )
        {
            newCategories.Add(new Category { Name = item });
        }
    }

    CreateCategories(newList);

    return GetAllCategories().ToList();
}
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Contains(TKey value)`

So you can replace your foreach loop by

`var newCategories = categories
                      .Where(m => !existedCategory.Contains(m))
                      .Select(m => new Category{Name = m}).toList()`

By the way, I don't see the need of a `LookUp<TKey, TValue>`, you could use a `HashSet<T>`

```
var existedCategory = new HashSet(GetAllCategories().Select(x => x.Name).ToList());
```

So your method would be

```
public List<Category> ExistingCategories(string[] categories)
{
    var existingCategories = new HashSet(GetAllCategories().Select(x => x.Name).ToList());

    var newCategories = categories
                      .Where(m => !existingCategories .Contains(m))
                      .Select(m => new Category{Name = m}).toList());

    //assuming this method will add and save to your db
    CreateCategories(newCategories);

    return GetAllCategories().ToList();
}
```